# Codeigniter mysql join didn't work

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I've a db that have 2 tables, and a search keyword, how can i join the tables, to do the select's in all the tables?

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tracks', 'genres');
$this->db->join('genres', 'genres.genreid = tracks.genre_id');

$this->db->or_where('tracks.title', $key);
$this->db->or_where('tracks.author', $key);
$this->db->or_where('genres.genreid', $key);
$this->db->order_by('tracks.rate', 'ASC');
$q = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: 1) you should use ->where() the first time, not all ->or_where();   Echo $this->db->last_query() & compare to what you are trying to achieve, then come edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

you have to have one table in from and the rest in the join

$this->db->from('tracks');

Answer (score 0):

It also pays to use the join statement to do the job of your where clause(s). If you do join and then where it selects all of the join between the tables and then applies where, but with ANDs in the join, there's less work to be done for the db.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tracks');
$this->db->join('genres', 'genres.genreid = tracks.genre_id');
$this->db->where('tracks.title', $key);
$this->db->or_where('tracks.author', $key);
$this->db->or_where('genres.genreid', $key);
$this->db->order_by('tracks.rate', 'ASC');
$q = $this->db->get();
```

This is the correct way of using it. You are using same table in FROM clause and JOIN this is problem. Another thing is that you are missing WHERE clause and only  using or where.